# Creatuing categories from a column of data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following data

```
Place   program personID    Diff
ABC pro1         123       -2
ABC pro1         234        3
ABC pro2         123        4
ABC pro3         123       -8
ABC pro3         234        4
ABC pro3         345        5
XYZ pro1         987       -6
XYZ pro1         765        1
XYZ pro1         657        2
XYZ pro2         987       -5
XYZ pro3         987       -7
XYZ pro3         765        1
XYZ pro3         345        2
XYZ pro1         438       -6
```

I want to create a table something like the below

```
Place   Program LessThan0   GreaterThan0
ABC        pro1         1   1
ABC        pro2         0   1
ABC        pro3         1   2
XYZ        pro1         2   2
XYZ        pro2         1   0
XYZ        pro3         1   2
```

I have written the code in the following SQL fiddle,

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7c0ce/1

But somehow I am not getting the summary I want. It is more detailed than required. How should MY SQL statement be modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close.  I replaced the case-when with sum(if()) statements.

```
Select Place, program, 
Sum(if(DiffMonth < 0,1,0)) AS Less,
Sum(if(DiffMonth > 0,1,0)) AS Great
from Table1 GROUP BY Place, program;
```